# Notice: Undefined offset in array php

Tags: php, arrays, undefined, offset

I am getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined offset in array php

Does anyone know where my mistake is?

```
//$forme count of my array 
for( $counter = 0; $counter < $forme; $counter++ )  {

    if($az[$counter] > 0)
    {
        $test=$connect->fetch_all("select * from `tbl_jobs_numbers` where `sub_id`='".$Subid[$counter]."' && `job_id`='".$JobID."' && `city_id`='".$ostan."' limit '".$az [ $counter ]."' , '".$ta[ $counter ]."'") ;

        foreach($test as $puriya)
        {
            print $mobiles=$puriya['number']."<br/>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $test=$connect->fetch_all("select * from `tbl_jobs_numbers` where `sub_id`='".$Subid[$counter]."' && `job_id`='".$JobID."' && `city_id`='".$ostan."' ") ;

        foreach($test as $puriya)
        {
            //print $mobiles=$puriya['number']."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have error here if($az[$counter] > 0) {

Comment: Where is `$az` defined?

Comment: @$az=$security->Check_Post($_POST['az']);
@$ta=$security->Check_Post($_POST['ta']);

Comment: The error that you have shown suggests that your error is in a snippet that you haven't shown us, since it states the error is in a for loop, and I can't seem to find the relevant code in the example. Also, please tidy up the question by being more formal and clear.

Comment: What does `Check_Post` return? We need more of your code, or it returns a string, int, non-array, which is the issue.

Comment: Check_Post (security function) filtering for sql injection my error hapend in this line if($az[$counter] > 0) {

Comment: Also: What value does `$counter` have? Looks like the `$az` array doesn't  contain an element numbered `$counter`

Comment: Yes, I know what you've said. If your not going to provide the code not much to do... @nhee `$counter` is incrementing, starts at 0.

Comment: $counter is a counter for my array to insert in db start from 0 to my count array  and $az is a variable for limit in select like this query  $test=$connect->fetch_all("select * from `tbl_jobs_numbers` where `sub_id`='".$Subid[$counter]."' && `job_id`='".$JobID."' && `city_id`='".$ostan."' limit '".$az [ $counter ]."' , '".$ta[ $counter ]."'") ;
     foreach($test as $puriya)
     {
      print $mobiles=$puriya['number']."<br/>";
     }

Comment: Ok, so if `$az[0]` is undefined then most likely your security check function doesn't work.

Comment: Edited the post for you. Good formating & clarity goes a long way to get answers here.

Comment: So... in `Check_Post` what does `return` have?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over each item of your array, the easier approach would be to use `foreach` (based on the not :

```
// array_values to make sure that the keys are numeric
foreach (array_values($az) as $index => $item) {
    if ($item > 0) {
        $test=$connect->fetch_all("select * from `tbl_jobs_numbers` where `sub_id`='".$Subid[$index]."' && `job_id`='".$JobID."' && `city_id`='".$ostan."' limit '".$az[$index]."' , '".$ta[$index]."'") ;

        foreach($test as $puriya)
        {
            print $mobiles=$puriya['number']."<br/>";
        }
    } else {
        $test=$connect->fetch_all("select * from `tbl_jobs_numbers` where `sub_id`='".$Subid[$index]."' && `job_id`='".$JobID."' && `city_id`='".$ostan."' ") ;

        foreach($test as $puriya)
        {
            //print $mobiles=$puriya['number']."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

This should avoid the undefined index error for `$az`.